# How to create $modelValue when it is undefined in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am busy creating a time input box directive. The HTML looks like this:

`<time-input data-ng-model="model.Time"></time-input>`

It is possible that `model.Time` is `null`. This means also off course that `$modelValue` of the `ngModelController` is undefined. But when I want to create / set the `$modelValue`, it is set back to undefined and I don't know why.

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martijngr/Tjjg8/1/) where you can see my problem in action. As you can see time 1 is working, but time 2 is not. As soon as you enter a valid value for time 2, it is removed.

Can someone explain why this is and how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to put model by hands...it automatically put there a value you return from parser as well as view has the value that formatter returns

[works here](http://jsfiddle.net/Tjjg8/8/)

So your parser looks like this and updateTimeInModel returns object for model:

```
controller.$parsers.unshift(function (value) {
   if (!value) return;
     var valid = regEx.test(value);

     controller.$setValidity('validTime', valid);

     if (valid) {
       return updateTimeInModel();
     }

     console.log(controller.$modelValue);
     return null;

 })
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! But could you explain why my code don't work? Why are you returning null? So the value returned by a parser or formatter function will be set as the `$modelValue`, is that correct?

Comment: @Martijn: The value returned by parsers will be set as `$modelValue`, the value returned by formatters will be displayed in the control

Comment: @KhanhTO: Thanks. But I still don't understand why my code doesn't work. In fact I am also returning a valid and filled object, but this seems to be ignored. Can you explain why?

Comment: @Martijn Cause if you look insight angular, when you set $modelValue manualy and return it from the function, value you return suposed to be set into $modelValue and run all the listeners notifications. And this is happens only if $modelValue !== retunedValue. So setting manually model you break the angular mechanism of watcher notifications. I assume(not sure) that real set of model happens somewhere there, because instantly after that model becames null.

Comment: @Fedor Skrynnikov, that makes sense. Thanks a lot!